# How to mirror 1000 databases on SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mirroring

We are implementing a mirroring  for ms-sql 64bit 2008 database. Are there are limits to how many databases can be mirrored? We are going to mirror 1000 small databases with a total size of 2TB. Network bandwidth is not an issue.

Have anybody done that?

Answer (score 1):

With 32bit SQL Server, there are limits due to the number of worker threads - Paul Randal blogged about it - his blog is mentioned on the following KB:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2001270

The SQLCAT team blogged about best practices with mirroring on 64bit, and this should help you decide appriopriately:
http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2010/02/10/mirroring-a-large-number-of-databases-in-a-single-sql-server-instance.aspx